# Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_CameraPageState.takePicture.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I have been trying to finish navigation for my flutter app, but I keep getting "NoSuchMethodError: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function' _CameraPageState.takePicture..". This error occurs after taking a picture and using the use on-pressed on AddNewBuddyPage to create an object add to my List on DashboardPage. Below is the class & function where the error is coming from.

```
    class CameraPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraPage({Key? key, required this.cameras}) : super(key: key);

  final List<CameraDescription>? cameras;

  @override
  State<CameraPage> createState() => _CameraPageState();
}
class _CameraPageState extends State<CameraPage> {
  late CameraController _cameraController;
  bool _isRearCameraSelected = true;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initCamera(widget.cameras![0]);
  }

  Future takePicture() async {
    if (!_cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      return null;
    }
    if (_cameraController.value.isTakingPicture) {
      return null;
    }
    try {
      await _cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);
      XFile picture = await _cameraController.takePicture();

      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
                  AddNewBuddyPage(addBuddy: () {}, image: picture)));
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error occured while taking picture: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }
  Future initCamera(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    _cameraController =
        CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.high);
    try {
      await _cameraController.initialize().then((_) {
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(() {});
      });
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      debugPrint("camera error $e");
    }
  }
```

I have no issue generating the picture and passing it to AddNewBuddyPage, but once I click on the button to create a new Object of type PlantBuddyModel I cannot navigate to the DashboardPage due to "NoSuchMethodError" error.

```
  class AddNewBuddyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function addBuddy;
  XFile image;
  AddNewBuddyPage({super.key, required this.addBuddy, required this.image});

  @override
  State<AddNewBuddyPage> createState() => _AddNewBuddyPageState();
}

class _AddNewBuddyPageState extends State<AddNewBuddyPage> {
  final plantNameController = TextEditingController();
  final heightController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: const Text('Create New Plant Buddy'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                controller: plantNameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Plant Name',
                    hintText: 'Enter your Plant\'s Name'),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: TextField(
                controller: heightController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Plant Height',
                    hintText: 'Enter your Plant\'s Height'),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await availableCameras().then((value) => Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => CameraPage(cameras: value))));
              },
              child: const Text("Take a Picture"),
            ),
            Image.file(
              File(widget.image!.path),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              width: 250,
              height: 200,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 250,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {

                  widget.addBuddy(PlantDataModel(
                    plantName: plantNameController.text,
                    height: double.parse(heightController.text),
                    date: DateFormat.yMMMd().format(DateTime.now()),
                    id: DateTime.now().toString(), image: widget.image,
                  ));
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'Add Buddy',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the function responsible for adding objects to the List on DashboardPage below & the model.

```
class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {
  final List<PlantDataModel> currentPlantBuddyList = [

  ];
  late XFile image = XFile('path');
  void _addNewPlantBuddy(PlantDataModel buddy) {
    setState(() {
      image = XFile(buddy.image.path);
      currentPlantBuddyList.add(buddy);
    });
  }

class PlantDataModel extends StatelessWidget {
  final String plantName;
  final double height;
  final String date;
  final String id;
  final XFile image;

  PlantDataModel(
      {required this.plantName,
      required this.height,
      required this.date,
      required this.id, required this.image, });
```

If you could please help I would appreciate it. New to flutter :(